# Entropy calculation given joint probability function

Tags: probability, information-theory

I am trying to solve the exercise below and I am very confused.

Exercise: Given three random variables with joint probability distribution function:
$$p(x, y, z)=p(x)p(y|x)p(z|x)$$
with

$ X: p(X=0)= p(X=1)= 1/4, \ p(X=2)=1/2 ,$
$ Y: p(Y=0| X=0)= p(Y=1| X=1)= 1, \ p(Y=0| X=2) = p(Y=1|X=2)=1/2 ,$
$ Z: p(Z=0|X=0)= p(Z=0|X=1)=p(Z=1|X=2)=1.$

Find $H(X),\ H(Y), \ H(Z).$

For $H(X)$:

$H(X)=-\sum_{i=1}^3p(x_i)log_2(p(x_i))=3/2$.

I would like your help to find $H(Y)$ and try the rest by myself.

**EDIT** Ι followed your suggestions and I found the solution but I would  like a second opinion. So here is my solution.

$H(X)=-∑_{i=1}^3p_X (x_i )  log_2⁡(p_X (x_i ))  
      = -P(X=0)  log_2⁡(P(X=0))-P(X=1)  log_2⁡(P(X=1))-P(X=2)  log_2⁡(P(X=2))
      =-1/4  log_2⁡(1/4)-1/4  log_2⁡(1/4)-1/2  log_2⁡(1/2) 
      =-3/2=1,5 bits.$

$H(Y)=-∑_{i=1}^2p_Y (y_i )  log_2⁡(p_Y (y_i ))  
     = -P(Y=0)  log_2⁡(P(Y=0))-P(Y=1)log_2⁡(P(Y=1)) 
     =-1/2  log_2⁡(1/2)-1/2  log_2⁡(1/2)=1 bit. $

$H(Z)=-∑_{i=1}^2p_Z (z_i )log_2⁡(p_Z (z_i ))  
     = -P(Ζ=0)log_2⁡(P(Ζ=0))-P(Ζ=1) log_2⁡(P(Ζ=1))
           =-1/2 log_2⁡(1/2)-1/4 log_2⁡(1/4) 
           =1 bits.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you compute the probability, you should be able to compute the entropy.

$$P(Y=y_i) = \sum_{x=0}^2P(Y=y_i|X=x)P(X=x)$$

Comment: I would like to ask you if it is straightforward the fact that $H(Y|Z)=H(Z|Y)=0$ and as a result $H(Y,Z)=H(Z)=H(Y)$.

Comment: if $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, $H(Y|Z)=H(Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborately for $H(Y)$,

$$P(Y = y) = \sum_{i = 0, 1, 2} P(Y=y, X= i)$$
$$P(Y = y) = \sum_{i = 0, 1, 2} P(Y=y | X= i) \cdot P(X=i)$$

Given,

$$P(Y=0 | X=0) = 1 \implies P(Y=0, X=0) = \frac{1}{4}$$ since $P(X=0) = \frac{1}{4}$ and similarly, $$P(Y=1 | X=1) = 1 \implies P(Y=1, X=1) = \frac{1}{4}$$

$$P(X=0) = \frac{1}{4} = \ P(X=0, Y=0)\  + \ P(X=1, Y=0)$$
This implies $ \ \ P(Y=0, X=1) = 0$ (since $P(X=0, Y=0) = \frac{1}{4}$)

Similarly you can find out that $P(Y=1, X=0) = 0$

Hence $P(Y=0)$ can be calculated as,
$$P(Y=0) = P(Y=0, X=0) + P(Y=0, X=1) + P(Y=0, X=2)$$ which turns out to be $\frac{1}{2}$ and so $P(Y=0) \ = P(Y=1) \ = \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore,$$H(Y) = -\bigg[\frac{1}{2} log_2\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg) + \frac{1}{2} log_2\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)\bigg] = 1 $$